# Sha-out sign not matching in Ogone

Tags: php, payment, sha

I'm trying to make a payment plugin for my webshop for Ogone ideal payments. I can make a payment, but when I return I cannot get the SHA-signs to match.

I have the following get request on return:

```
orderID=476&amount=90%2E82&PM=iDEAL&ACCEPTANCE=0000000000&STATUS=9&PAYID=43934127&NCERROR=0&BRAND=iDEAL&SHASIGN=5AB0A065BAA83C5D807249A66E661ACBB6709B8F
```

According to the documentation, I have to order the keys alphabetically and only hash those that are allowed.

These are the allowed keys:

```
['AAVADDRESS', 'AAVCHECK', 'AAVZIP', 'ACCEPTANCE', 'ALIAS', 'AMOUNT', 'BRAND', 'CARDNO', 'CCCTY', 'CN', 'COMPLUS', 'CURRENCY', 'CVCCHECK', 'DCC_COMMPERCENTAGE', 'DCC_CONVAMOUNT', 'DCC_CONVCCY', 'DCC_EXCHRATE', 'DCC_EXCHRATESOURCE', 'DCC_EXCHRATETS', 'DCC_INDICATOR', 'DCC_MARGINPERCENTAGE', 'DCC_VALIDHOUS', 'DIGESTCARDNO', 'ECI', 'ED', 'ENCCARDNO', 'IP', 'IPCTY', 'NBREMAILUSAGE', 'NBRIPUSAGE', 'NBRIPUSAGE_ALLTX', 'NBRUSAGE', 'NCERROR', 'ORDERID', 'PAYID', 'PM', 'SCO_CATEGORY', 'SCORING', 'STATUS', 'TRXDATE', 'VC'];
```

I made this method to make the hash:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
protected function getShaOutSign()
{
    $hash = '';
    $values = \Input::all();
    $values = array_change_key_case($values, CASE_UPPER);
    ksort($values);

    foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($key, $this->shaOut)) {

            if(!empty($value))
            {
                $hash .= $key . '=' . $values[$key] . $this->settings->shaout;
            }
        }
    }

    return  strtoupper(sha1($hash));
}
```

I'm 100% sure the SHA out key is correct.

The string it makes before I do SHA1:

```
ACCEPTANCE=0000000000abcDEFghj1234560987654AMOUNT=90.82abcDEFghj1234560987654BRAND=iDEALabcDEFghj1234560987654ORDERID=476abcDEFghj1234560987654PAYID=43934127abcDEFghj1234560987654PM=iDEALabcDEFghj1234560987654STATUS=9abcDEFghj1234560987654
```

And the final hash I get is:

```
68E459CB933E04B582A5D564CE6F591D5819B7F1
```

No matter what I try, I just can't get it to match it with the one in the $_GET request.

My sha-out key: abcDEFghj1234560987654

What can I try next?

Comment: Something is wrong with your calculation. If I recalculate the hash I get the correct one though

Comment: hehe ye i noticed something was wrong, can't figure out what tho :(

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/QY5t99nN) is what I use to calculate it, with `$sha_parms` is the full `$_POST` or in your case `$_GET`

Comment: Indeed, yours is working. I'll check out the differences. Could you make an answer so i can accept it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sha out calculation is wrong. This is the code I use in my projects to calculate it, `$sha_parms` is the full response of Ogone. So `$_POST` or `$_GET`

```
            /**
            * Function to calculate the sha that is received from Ogone
            */
            public function getShaOut($sha_parms, $sha_out = null) {
                    $sha_out = $sha_out ?: self::PASS_PHRASE_OUT;
                    $sha_parms = $this->ogoneSort($sha_parms);

                    $sha_string = '';
                    foreach ($sha_parms as $key => $value) {
                            if ($key != 'SHASIGN' && $value != '') {
                                    $sha_string .= $key . '=' . $value . $sha_out;
                            }
                    }

                    //return($sha_string);
                    return strtoupper(sha1($sha_string));
            }              

            /**
            *
            *
            **/
            private function ogoneSort($array) {
                    $arrayToSort = array();
                    $origArray = array();
                    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                            $arrayToSort[strtolower($key)] = $value;
                            //stores the original value in an array
                            $origArray[strtolower($key)] = $key;
                    }

                    ksort($arrayToSort);

                    $sortedArray = array();
                    foreach($arrayToSort as $key => $value) {
                            //switch the lowercase keys back to their originals
                            $key = strtoupper($origArray[$key]);
                            $sortedArray[$key] = $value;
                    }

                    return $sortedArray;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clearly that part:

```
if(!empty($value))
{
    $hash .= $key . '=' . $values[$key] . $this->settings->shaout;
}
```

Your request contains '...&NCERROR=0...'.

So the value is 0. And 0 is empty.

I had the same problem. But I used array_filter() function:

```
$parameters = array_filter($parameters);
```

Also array_filter() removed my 'empty' ncerror field.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still uses legacy Ogone/Ingenico/Wordline nowdays? ;)

The solution by @DarkBee is correct, however could be simplified:

```
private function calculateHash($secret, $fields)
{
    $hash = '';

    ksort($fields, SORT_STRING | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
    $fields = array_change_key_case($fields, CASE_UPPER);

    foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
        if (!empty($field)) {
            $hash .= sprintf('%s=%s%s', $key, $field, $secret);
        }
    }

    return strtoupper(sha1($hash));
}
```

First you need sort the array of fields "as is" keeping the current keys case. Then convert those keys to upper case. And only after that concatenate the result array to calculate hash.

Comment: Some of my project still rely on the code posted in my answer, so yes some people still use Ingenico :3